# Search .dat file of structures C++

Tags: c++

I am working on a book inventory program but I am having trouble with my `searchBook()` function. I want to be able to search for every instance of the substring within the bookfile and display the title and author of each book found from which the user can select the book they want to view the full structure.
My struct:

```
struct Book {
    string title, author, pubDate, synop, isbn;
}b[1000];
```

Book.dat contains up to 1000 of these structures (ignore colors):

```
Book Title
Last, First
11/12/2015
This book is about...
1234567890
```

My searchBook function:

```
void searchBooks(ifstream& bookfile, Book b){
    int quit = 0;
    do{
        if (!bookfile){
            cout << "ERROR: book.dat not found...nothing to do here.";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        string s;
        while (getline(bookfile, s))
            bookfile.close();
        cout << "Enter search: ";
        string searchBook;
        getline(cin, searchBook);
        vector<size_t> positions;
        do
        {
            if(s.find(searchBook) != string::npos){
                size_t pos = s.find(searchBook, 0);
                positions.push_back(pos);
                pos = s.find(searchBook,pos+1);
                cout << "Found " << searchBook << " at line " << pos << endl;
            }
            else {
                while (string :: npos) {
                    cout << "End of file reached...Search again: ";
                    getline(cin, searchBook);
                }
            }
        } while(getline(bookfile, searchBook));
        cout << "What do you want to do with this line?" << endl;
        cout << "1-Edit" << endl;
        cout << "2-Delete" << endl;
        cout << "3-Search Again" << endl;
        cout << "4-Quit" << endl;
        int sl;
        cin >> sl;
        switch (sl) {
            case 1:
                editBook(bookfile, searchBook);
                break;

            case 2:
                deleteBook(bookfile, searchBook);
                break;
            case 3:
                searchBooks(bookfile, b);
            case 4:
                quit = 1;
                break;
        }
    } while (quit !=1);
}
```

Comment: You don't provide us `book.dat` and your question is too broad - you say you have problem with 3 functions. Try to pick one part that doesn't work. We don't need the whole program, we need just one small working sample. This is not "finish my program" service (no offence).

Comment: Second the above. Try to provide the shortest sample you can with a) what happens and b) what you expect to happen. In the meantime, there's a few immediate problems: you're opening the same file for reading and writing simultaneously, and your search function appears to try to find the entered book name in `line`, but `line` never contains anything but an empty string. (Also why are you dividing `lineNumber` by 1000?)

Comment: I have made changes to my post.